# How to aligne text in a table using HTML in a Jupyter Notebook markdown cell?

Tags: python, html, markdown, jupyter

I'd like to align the text in a table to the left using HTML code (in a jupyter notebook markdown cell).

The text-align doesn't work.

Here is how the cell looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0DKw.png)

Here is the code I use:

```
<table>
  <tr style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
    <td>Header 1</td>
    <td>Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-size: 16px; text-align: right;">
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-size: 16px; text-align: right;">
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried using text-align, try using "ALIGN="center""

So your code should look something like this...

```
<table>
  <tr style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
    <td>Header 1</td>
    <td>Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-size: 16px; text-align: right;">
    <td ALIGN="center">Cell 1</td>
    <td ALIGN="center">Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-size: 16px; text-align: right;">
    <td ALIGN="center">Cell 3</td>
    <td ALIGN="center">Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```